# How to specifiy a file name in the url of a download link specifically for YouTube

Tags: php, youtube

The download manager that i have cannot get the name of the file from the download link specifically YouTube download links.So how can I covert the link lets say:

https://r11.blah.com/video?=blah

to

My guess

https://r11.blah.com/video?=blah.........filename=blah.mp4

current links save as "videoplayblack"

```
https://r11---sn-hc57en7z.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pl=24&id=o-APNCabdUt7blTYaiKpbm0qOfC2srnukOhjGKRgTNdwAR&mime=video%2Fmp4&sver=3&ms=au&mm=31&mv=m&mt=1457286590&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mn=sn-hc57en7z&ip=154.123.7.213&key=yt6&expire=1457308298&itag=22&requiressl=yes&upn=QH8Qb2F4U6w&dur=177.934&initcwndbps=95000&source=youtube&fexp=3300133%2C3300164%2C3310844%2C3312381%2C9416126%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423661%2C9423662%2C9429363&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&lmt=1417476827604992&signature=B03A0FF98EDF95A675E049854FC9499DEAC8A5A1.BBFB552846DB08C6F682C6D975FF747D094ACD52&title=DJ%20Snake%20(feat.%20Alesia)%20-%20Bird%20Machine%20(Jingle%20Bells%20Edition)
```

Some other download managers magically grab the file name I do not know how.